# WinForms ComboBox DataBound to Enum - Format String

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, enums, string-formatting

This is just an investigation into the best way to format string values on a `ComboBox` originating from an `Enum`.

I know I can databind a `ComboBox` to an `Enum` like so:

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxNames.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Names));
    }
}

public enum Names
{
    JohnDoe,
    JaneDoe,
    JohnJackson,
    JackJohnson
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I would like to format the display values of the `ComboBox` such that there is a space between the PascalCase string values, while also passing through the `Enum` value of the selected item which I can use in a `switch` statement later on:

```cs
switch ((Names)comboBoxNames.SelectedItem)
{
    case Names.JohnDoe:
        // Do something John Doe-specific
        break;
    case Names.JaneDoe:
        // Do something Jane Doe-specific
        break;
    case Names.JohnJackson:
        // Do something John Jackson-specific
        break;
    case Names.JackJohnson:
        // Do something Jack Johnson-specific
        break;
}
```

I know that there is a `ComboBox.FormatString` property but I am unsure about how to use it to format the `Names` enum the way that I want.

Is this possible? I would prefer not to use attributes on the `Enum` because using that ultimately involves using reflection which seems like overkill for something that seems so simple. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to format string values on a `ComboBox` originating from an `Enum` that I like, without requiring the `ComboBox.FormatString` property or the `Format` event: use a `Dictionary<Enum, string>`. Sample code below:

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxNames.DataBindToEnum(default(Names).ToDictionary());
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((KeyValuePair<Names, string>)comboBoxNames.SelectedItem).Key)
        {
            case Names.JohnDoe:
                // Do something John Doe-specific
                MessageBox.Show(@"John Doe!");
                break;
            case Names.JaneDoe:
                // Do something Jane Doe-specific
                MessageBox.Show(@"Jane Doe!");
                break;
            case Names.JohnJackson:
                // Do something John Jackson-specific
                MessageBox.Show(@"John Jackson!");
                break;
            case Names.JackJohnson:
                // Do something Jack Johnson-specific
                MessageBox.Show(@"Jack Johnson!");
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum Names
{
    JohnDoe,
    JaneDoe,
    JohnJackson,
    JackJohnson
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<T, string> ToDictionary<T>(this T enumeration)
    {
        if (!enumeration.GetType().IsEnum) return null;

        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<T>().ToList();
        return enumValues.ToDictionary(enumValue => enumValue, enumValue => enumValue.ToString().Spaceify());
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Spaceify(this string self)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < self.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(self[i - 1]) && char.IsUpper(self[i]) ||
                self[i - 1] != ' ' && char.IsUpper(self[i]) && char.IsLower(self[i + 1]))
            {
                self = self.Insert(i, " ");
            }
        }
        return self;
    }
}

public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void DataBindToEnum<T>(this ListControl listControl, IDictionary<T, string> enumAsDictionary)
    {
        listControl.DataSource = new BindingSource(enumAsDictionary, null);
        listControl.DisplayMember = "Value";
        listControl.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- Instead of setting the `ComboBox.DataSource` directly as a list of the `enum`, set it using a `Dictionary<Enum, string>` and set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` accordingly (extension method `DataBindToEnum`)
- Currently we cannot use the `enum` keyword as a type restriction (something like `public static Dictionary<T, string> ToDictionary<T>(this T enumeration) **where T : enum**`). This is why an `enum` check is required in the body of that method
- The `Spaceify` extension method adds spaces to PascalCase strings (handles acronyms as well)
- The "magic" line is where I use the `default` keyword on the `enum` so that I can work on it as a list-type object and get around the issue of invoking a method on an "*instance*" of the `enum`
- Finally, when using out the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` I need to cast it to a `KeyValuePair<Enum, string>` and pull out the `Key` which I can use in my `switch` statement. No more magic strings!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

this is easy, just add the format event on your combobox and make it look like this:

```
private void comboBoxNames_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(e.Value.ToString().Length +1);
    newText.Append(e.Value.ToString()[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < e.Value.ToString().Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(e.Value.ToString()[i]) && e.Value.ToString()[i - 1] != ' ')
            newText.Append(' ');
        newText.Append(e.Value.ToString()[i]);
    }
    e.Value = newText.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This indeed works but I was hoping to avoid events since I have many dropdowns and I don't like polluting the code-behind with event handlers (personal preference). Is this not possible using the properties directly accessible from the `ComboBox` control?

Comment: As far as i know there is no possible way to format the items without an event and still keep the enum values.